# Can't get module communication to work with Node.JS and Azure IOT Edge

Tags: node.js, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to deploy a device to my Edge device that simulates temp data with Node.js. I have gone though and made my certificates and added it to my Node.Js module and imported the cert I get

> Could not connect: mqtt.js returned Failure on first connection (Not authorized): self signed certificate in certificate chain error

in the logs for the module. This is what I have in the config.toml. I tried with a host name got the same result I am getting using the IP address. (Wanted to remove DNS as an issue)

```
    hostname = "10.90.27.150"
    
    trust_bundle_cert = "file:///home/edge/certificates/certs/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem"
    
    [edge_ca]
    
    cert = "file:///home/edge/certificates/certs/iot-edge-device-ca-10.90.27.150-full-chain.cert.pem"
    
    pk = "file:///home/edge/certificates/private/iot-edge-device-ca-10.90.27.150.key.pem"
```

Here is my module I am trying to use:

```
    // Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
    // Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.
    
    'use strict';
    
    var fs = require('fs');
    var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
    // Uncomment one of these transports and then change it in fromConnectionString to test other transports
    // var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-http').Http;
    // var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-amqp').Amqp;
    var Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
    var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;
    
    // 1) Obtain the connection string for your downstream device and to it
    //    append this string GatewayHostName=<edge device hostname>;
    // 2) The Azure IoT Edge device hostname is the hostname set in the config.yaml of the Azure IoT Edge device
    //    to which this sample will connect to.
    //
    // The resulting string should look like the following
    //  "HostName=<iothub_host_name>;DeviceId=<device_id>;SharedAccessKey=<device_key>;GatewayHostName=<edge device hostname>"
    var deviceConnectionString = "HostName=*removed*-devices.net;DeviceId=Virtual_Humidity_Simulator;SharedAccessKey=*removed*;GatewayHostName=10.90.27.150" //process.env.DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING;
    
    // Path to the Edge "owner" root CA certificate
    var edge_ca_cert_path = "./azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem";
    
    // fromConnectionString must specify a transport constructor, coming from any transport package.
    var client = Client.fromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, Protocol);
    
    var connectCallback = function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
      } else {
        console.log('Client connected');
        client.on('message', function (msg) {
          console.log('Id: ' + msg.messageId + ' Body: ' + msg.data);
          // When using MQTT the following line is a no-op.
          client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));
          // The AMQP and HTTP transports also have the notion of completing, rejecting or abandoning the message.
          // When completing a message, the service that sent the C2D message is notified that the message has been processed.
          // When rejecting a message, the service that sent the C2D message is notified that the message won't be processed by the device. the method to use is client.reject(msg, callback).
          // When abandoning the message, IoT Hub will immediately try to resend it. The method to use is client.abandon(msg, callback).
          // MQTT is simpler: it accepts the message by default, and doesn't support rejecting or abandoning a message.
        });
    
        // Create a message and send it to the IoT Hub every two seconds
        var sendInterval = setInterval(function () {
          var windSpeed = 10 + (Math.random() * 4); // range: [10, 14]
          var temperature = 20 + (Math.random() * 10); // range: [20, 30]
          var humidity = 60 + (Math.random() * 20); // range: [60, 80]
          var data = JSON.stringify({ deviceId: 'myFirstDownstreamDevice', windSpeed: windSpeed, temperature: temperature, humidity: humidity });
          var message = new Message(data);
          message.properties.add('temperatureAlert', (temperature > 28) ? 'true' : 'false');
          console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());
          client.sendEvent(message, printResultFor('send'));
        }, 2000);
    
        client.on('error', function (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        });
    
        client.on('disconnect', function () {
          clearInterval(sendInterval);
          client.removeAllListeners();
          client.open(connectCallback);
        });
      }
    };
    
    // Provide the Azure IoT device client via setOptions with the X509
    // Edge root CA certificate that was used to setup the Edge runtime
    var options = {
      ca : fs.readFileSync(edge_ca_cert_path, 'utf-8'),
    };
    
    client.setOptions(options, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('SetOptions Error: ' + err);
      } else {
        client.open(connectCallback);
      }
    });
    
    // Helper function to print results in the console
    function printResultFor(op) {
      return function printResult(err, res) {
        if (err) console.log(op + ' error: ' + err.toString());
        if (res) console.log(op + ' status: ' + res.constructor.name);
      };
    }
```

I tried to follow the steps here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-test-certificates?view=iotedge-2020-11#create-iot-edge-device-ca-certificates

I also tried the steps here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-test-certificates?view=iotedge-2020-11

But I can't get it work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or have better directions to give me?

Answer (score 0):

Certificate, is a file that binds the owner identity with his public key. This bond is signed and confirmed by a reliable third party which called the Certificate Authority (CA).

**Device CA certificate** is a self-signed certificate that is only meant for development and testing scenarios, not production.

If you are using a self-signed certificate, that means it's not secure which is why you are getting this error. So you can solve it by  setting the following in the request.

```js
rejectUnauthorized: false
```

But remember **If you turn on unauthorized certificates, you will not be protected at all and it will be exposed to MITM attack for not validating identity**.

Another and more secure way is by specifying the CA that you expect in a http request request like the following snippet :

```js
ca: [fs.readFileSync([certificate path], {encoding: 'utf-8'})]
```

From [Node version 7.3.0](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file), `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable is introduced to pass in a CA certificate file. This allows the “root” CAs to be extended with the extra certificates in file.

Check the following documents for more information:

- [Self Signed Certificates and Certifcate Chains](https://github.com/nicferrier/nodejs-self-signed-cert-server-and-client)
- [Resolve Certificate Errors in a Node.js App](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-resolve-certificate-errors-in-nodejs-app-involving-ssl-calls-781ce48daded)
- [tls_connect_options_callback](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback)
- [MQTT JS Discussion](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/271)